# How to use existing DynamoDB tables in Dynamoose.js

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nestjs, dynamoose

We are creating DynamoDB tables in AWS using terraform.

Our application is a Nest.js application using
[nestjs-dynamoose](https://github.com/hardyscc/nestjs-dynamoose) and is deployed as a Lambda function. The lambda function is started without any error. The create option in dynamoose is set to false.

When trying to access the created tables the this.model.get([...]) never finishes:

```
const user = await this.model.get({id: instanceId});
console.log(user);
if (user) {
  return await this.model.update({
    value: token,
    id: instanceId,
  });
} else {
  return await this.model.create({id: instanceId, value: token});
}
```

If we do not create the tables with terraform and let dynamoose create the tables everything works smoothly.

How can we use the already existing tables from dynamoose?

Comment: `Also how can we apply the dynamoose schemas to the existing tables?` is a separate question and doesn't have enough information to answer. Please keep your questions limited to 1 specific question as opposed to multiple questions in one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [Models](https://dynamoosejs.com/guide/Model) there are two settings you can set: `create` & `waitForActive`. It sounds like your table is fully created, active, and ready to go.

If you set both of those settings to `false` this should work as you expect.

Here is an example of some code to achieve that:

```
const CatSchema = new dynamoose.Schema({"id": String, "age": Number});
const Cat = dynamoose.model("Cat", CatSchema, {
    "create": false,
    "waitForActive": false
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I did, but I realized I had streaming enabled for the DynamoDB tables. Disabling it seems to fix my issue. I will accept your answer.